# FIWARE Lab - Docker images connectivity issues building images

Tags: docker, centos7, openstack, fiware

Trying to install some GEs in a FIWARE Lab machine, the installations doesn't complete using Centos base image.

I tried the same process on a local virtual machine and i could get successfully installed the docker container.

Triying to install the FIWARE PEP Proxy (building image) using the docker instructions:
https://github.com/ging/fiware-pep-proxy/tree/master/extras/docker

```
sudo docker build -t pep-proxy-image .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 6.656 kB
Step 1/7 : FROM ubuntu:14.04
 ---> 578c3e61a98c
Step 2/7 : MAINTAINER FIWARE Wilma PEP Proxy Team. DIT-UPM
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 79f4c3dbc65b
Step 3/7 : WORKDIR /opt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e705b36ae1f3
Step 4/7 : RUN sudo apt-get update &&   sudo apt-get install make g++ software-properties-common python-software-properties -y &&       sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js -y &&     sudo apt-get update &&  sudo apt-get install nodejs git -y
---> Running in 7ee6f4ca98fa

Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg [916 B]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg [933 B]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg [916 B]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg [916 B]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release
```

I have full connectivity in host machine and also i opened the security rules on open-stack like web dashboard. Also I disabled the Centos firewall

```
systemctl disable firewalld
```

I have no problems if I download the image but i cant build on FIWARE Lab
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a matter with MTU. The VMs have a MTU of 1400 and dockers by default have a MTU 1500, so they don't work.

So, considering the installation described https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/ and based on the default network customization described here: https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/

We can configure docker0 creating the file /etc/docker/daemon.json using this configuration in order to make it just like the default one:

```
{
  "bip": "172.17.0.1/16",
  "fixed-cidr": "172.17.0.1/16",
  "mtu": 1400,
  "dns": ["8.8.8.8"]
}
```

Then after restarting the docker service, everything should correctly work.

Comment: Editing the json file with the parameters indicated works fine